# a Hash followed by some undefined characters are appearing at the end of my site urls in all pages

Tags: javascript, url, wordpress

have been going through an issue recently. I found that all of my site urls have something strange at the end. It's a hash followed by a series of characters. I know these type of things appear when you use shareThis or AddThis plugin in your site, but in my case, I don't use them. Moreover, the shareThis or AddThis hashes have some common formats like, `#sthashxxx` or `#.xxxx`

But in my case, the format is like,

```
domainname.com/#axzz3hDgnuhSm
```

And sometimes when I refreshed, I found once that the hash is changing as well with some other random values.

What could be the reason for this as any light on this will help me to get rid of this ugly looking URL's...!

Comment: It would be helpful for others if you list all your wordpress plugings.

Comment: Can you give us a link to your site? Have you checked in another browser? It's possible a browser add-on is doing this.

Comment: It shows the same in other browsers..! Tried on firefox.. Same result..

check this url -- http://www.healthandautoinsurance.org/

Comment: and can't name all the plugins name right now as I'm on mobile. My developer left me in this position but I'm sure that no addThis or shareThis plugin is there.! Thanks to all.